# Function template won't compile

Tags: c++, templates

I am just learning function templates and the template I created below doesn't compile and I am not sure what's wrong. I am trying to make an int variable and a double variable go into the template but I keep getting an error when I call the function. The error is:

> error: no matching function for call to 'LargestFunction(int&, double&)'|

and the code is as follows:

```
 template <class Temp>
    Temp LargestFunction(Temp a, Temp b){
        if(a > b){
            return a;
        }
    else
        return b;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int NumOne = 30;
        double NumTwo = 52.252;
        cout << LargestFunction(NumOne,NumTwo);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Which type do you propose `Temp` is?

Comment: I have two types that are going into the function, one is a double and one is an int, can't I use different types?

Comment: You can, but you can't deduce one type from two conflicting types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to support different types, you need to define the template with different template parameters.

   ```
   template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
   typename std::common_type<Lhs, Rhs>::type max(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) {
     return lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs;
   }
   ```

   This way you can pass different types and you'll get whatever the common type between them is.
2. If you want to only deal with equal types within the function, you can keep the template as-is.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   T max(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) {
       return lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs;
   }
   ```

   You need to then cast one of the parameters so that you have equal types.

   ```
   max(static_cast<double>(101), 4.2);
   ```

   Or, you could also explicitly specialize the function template, but this is discouraged in general.

   ```
   max<double>(101, 4.2);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know which type it should infer.  Should it be `int` or `double`?  In your template, `Temp` refers to a single type.  You are free to specify it by calling:

```
LargestFunction<double>(NumOne,NumTwo);
```

Or you could define your template to take `Temp1` and `Temp2` types.